# Added class unable to be selected for a new XIB

Tags: class, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I added a new class to solution (iOS), together with XIB and its designer.cs.

Problem is I cannot select this newly created class (NewAccountView.cs) in the XIB NewAccountView.xib properties (see the drop down list does not include my added class NewAccountView.cs.)

[image]

I am new to Xamarin and I am sure I am missing a crucial step here. Pls help.

Comment: Did you try typing the class name?

Comment: You can write the whole class name out and it will compile. Have you tried building and then re-selecting your `ViewController`? Also, if you add the code for the actual class, it might help to see if there's a clear issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the View or the View Controller template?

If you used the View template, then only the .xib is created and you would have had to create the View class separately, in which case it probably did not automatically add the class inheritance and the `Register` attribute to your class. Make sure your `NewAccountView` inherits from UIView (or some subclass of UIView as appropriate) and also that you register it. E.g.:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
...

[Register("NewAccountView")]
public class NewAccountView : UIView
{
    ...
}
```